# How to import dump.psql file to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql, navicat, phppgadmin

I want to import dump.psql file to PostgreSQL.

Postgres admin panel only supports executing sql files not psql.
How can I do this?

Comment: If your dump file is a SQL (aka "plain text") dump, then just run it with `psql`. What exactly is this "admin panel" you are talking about? Postgres doesn't have an "admin panel".

Comment: If it's a dump for `pg_restore`, PgAdmin has a "restore" option when you right click on database. Create a new blank database, right click, restore, etc. Otherwise use `psql -f ...`